# Where to find list of default dll files available on Windows (XP, Vista, 7, ...)?

Tags: windows, dll

Is there some list of .dll files that are available on the various *freshly-installed* Windows platforms (or at least, the recent ones like Win XP and Win 7)? I am looking for a list similar to  [this one for Windows 2000](http://labmice.techtarget.com/articles/standardexe.htm).

(I am compiling a python app with py2exe, and the application reports which dlls are required for potential distribution with the compiled application, but unfortunately it doesn't tell me which ones are installed by default)

Comment: I'm not really sure how useful that would be.  In addition to what DLLs are available in a default install, you also have to worry about what versions they are.  The application might use a function that was added to a DLL sometime after the initial release.  This seems like a question only the authors of py2exe could answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think [this](http://www.win7dll.info/) is what you're after (at least for Windows 7).

And [here's the Windows XP version](http://xpdll.nirsoft.net/).

Answer (score 0):

If you are targeting different windows versions with your application, it is a *really* good idea to set up a virtual test environment for each of the primary target platforms, for example, using [VMware](http://www.vmware.com), [MS Virtual PC](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3702) or [Oracle Virtual Box](http://www.virtualbox.org/). If you then still need the list of all available DLLs, just look in the windows folders after a fresh install in the virtual machine by yourself.

By the way, having a look on the py2exe tutorial site, the example shows up `ADVAPI32.dll`, 
`USER32.dll`,`SHELL32.dll` and `KERNEL32.dll` as DLLs on which the generated files depend. AFAIK those DLLs are primary windows components, not to be deployed by your program, and available under all Windows versions I had to deal with the last 15 years.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of the advantage of using VMs. Indeed, looking up the DLLs in the fresh install of each of these systems would work, but I like to think that someone had already done this before, and made it available online :-)
Thanks for the suggestion though