# Do these DLLs exist in default Windows systems?

Tags: windows, dll

I have a small Windows app that makes uses of these DLLs:

```
kernel32.dll
user32.dll
ole32.dll
oleaut32.dll
shlwapi.dll
urlmon.dll
wininet.dll
psapi.dll
```

Do all of these dlls already exist in a new Windows (XP/Vista/7) installation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

There's a good question about this, providing a source for such information: [Where to find list of default dll files available on Windows (XP, Vista, 7, ...)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3184924/where-to-find-list-of-default-dll-files-available-on-windows-xp-vista-7)